# Tkinter error in pycharm : root is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

Hi I am a novice programmer.I am trying to use tkinter in pycharm....
When i try to use root or any other function it doesn't show any suggestion and gives not defined error.The program works fine in idle. But cann't seem to get it work with pycharm.Please help.I have already installed tkinter package and its also enabled in project interpreter settings....
here's what I am trying to do...

```
    from tkinter import *

    root = Tk()

    topframe = Frame(root)
    topframe.pack()
    bottomframe = Frame(root)
    bottomframe.pack(side = BOTTOM)

    button1 = Button(topframe, text='Button 1', fg='red')
    button2 = Button(topframe, text='Button 2', fg='blue')
    button3 = Button(bottomframe, text='Button 3', fg='green')

    button1.pack(side = LEFT)
    button2.pack(side = LEFT)
    button3.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Quote the code that is giving you errors.

Comment: I am not getting any suggestions in pycharm . The code works fine in idle....

Comment: You must verify that the interpreter used in your pycharm project is the one for which tkinter is installed. (project -> preferences -> interpreter)

Comment: It is enabled....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this

```
from tkinter import Tk
root= Tk()
```

I also faced this problem before. This worked for me. I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Note **Tkinter** has been renamed to **tkinter** in Python 3

**tkinter —** Python interface to Tcl/Tk.(Tk itself is not part of Python; it is maintained at ActiveState)
source : [official Doc](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.html)

Also there are certain classes that don't get imported when you try to import with *. When working with tkinter.

turn Around:
Solution 1.

```
try:
    # for Python2
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    # for Python3
    from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
```

Solution 2:check correct version is installed in pycharm.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
root.mainloop()
```

Solution 3: Absolute Import

```
from tkinter import Tk
root= Tk()
w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
```

Comment: thanks I didn't knew that something like sol 1 can also be done.... It might sound silly but error occurred bcoz I also named my .py file tkinter... ;)   .. So pycharm was trying to import tk and other functions from my tkinter.py file....

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I found that when I typed `from tkinter` there were 2 different options; you need to choose the option with a file icon next to it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The issue you’re describing is unrelated to the problem the original poster had. The import line in their post, `from tkinter import *`, is the correct import for Tkinter in Python 3. Choosing an option with a file icon is IDE-specific, you should verify the import name in the code instead of relying on icons in cases like these.